# How can writing memory to a filebuffer mutate it?

Tags: c++, c, file, memory

For a while now, I have been experiencing an extremely odd problem when trying to write memory to a filebuffer in C++. The problem only occurs on MinGW. When I compile under gcc/linux, everything is fine.

[Debugging Session displaying the problem](http://uncommonsense.dyndns.org/memory.png)

So basically, I'm writing code from a memory buffer to a filebuffer, and the binary representation in the file ends up being different from the memory I wrote. No, the file is not being modified at a later point, I ensured this by using the debugger to exit the program after closing the file. I have no idea how something like this is even possible, I even used valgrind to see if there were any memory allocation problems, but nope.

I'll paste some of the related code.

```
/// a struct holding information about a data file
class ResourceFile {
public:
    string name;
    uint32 size;
    char* data;

    ResourceFile(string name, uint32 size);
};

ResourceFile::ResourceFile(string name, uint32 size)
    : name(name), size(size)
{
    // will be free'd in ResourceBuilder's destruction
    data = (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
}


/// Build a data resource from a set of files
class ResourceBuilder {
public:
    ofstream out; ///< File to put the resource into
    vector<ResourceFile> input; ///< List of input strings

    /// Add a file from disk to the resource
    void add_file(string filename);

    /// Create a file that the resource will be written to
    void create_file(string filename);

    ~ResourceBuilder();
};

void ResourceBuilder::create_file(string filename) {
    // open the specified file for output
    out.open(filename.c_str());
    uint16 number_files = htons(input.size());
    out.write((char*) &number_files, sizeof(uint16));

    foreach(vector<ResourceFile>,input,i) {
        ResourceFile& df = *i;
        uint16 name_size = i->name.size();
        uint16 name_size_network = htons(name_size);
        out.write((char*) &name_size_network, sizeof(uint16));
        out.write(i->name.c_str(),name_size);
        uint32 size_network = htonl(i->size);
        out.write((char*) &size_network, sizeof(i->size) );
        out.write(i->data, i->size);
    }

    out.close();

    /// \todo write the CRC
}
```

The following is how the memory is allocated in the first place. This is a possible source of error, because I copypasted it from somewhere else without bothering to understand it in detail, but I honestly don't know how the method in which I allocated memory could be a reason for filebuffer output being different from the memory that I'm writing.

```
void ResourceBuilder::add_file(string filename) {
    // loads a file and copies its content into memory
    // this is done by the ResourceFile class and there is a
    // small problem with this, namely that the memory is
    // allocated in the ResourceFile directly,
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    filebuf* pbuf=file.rdbuf();

    int size=pbuf->pubseekoff (0,ios::end,ios::in);
    pbuf->pubseekpos (0,ios::in);

    ResourceFile df(filename,size);

    pbuf->sgetn (df.data,size);

    file.close();

    input.push_back(df);
}
```

I'm really out of ideas. It's also not a bug pertaining to my compiler setup, as other people compiling the code under MinGW get the same error. The only explanation I can think of at this point is a bug with MinGW's filebuffer library itself, but I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode. When you open it in text mode on Windows, line feeds (0x0A) will get converted to CR/LF pairs (0x0D, 0x0A). On Linux you don't see this because Linux uses a single LF (0x0A) as the line terminator in text files, so no conversion is done.

Pass the `ios::binary` flag to the `ostream::open` method:

```
out.open(filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
```

You should also use this flag when reading binary files, so that the opposite conversion isn't performed:

```
ifstream file;
file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
```

Comment: *facepalms* Oh damn, now I feel stupid. Hours of looking at that piece of code, and overlooking such a simple thing.. Anyway, thanks! That fixed it just fine. Too bad I can't accept two answers since you two answered at the same time.

Comment: @cib It happens to everyone, I swear :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you open your file in text mode! In that case, `0x0a` (Linefeed) is converted to `0x0d0a` (Carriage return line feed). This is why you see a difference in the file and memory.

use `out.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::out);`